# What's the best place to insert http/https redirect in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a very large `.htaccess` file I have to edit.

This file starts this way:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

I have to add the following:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Should I add this two lines just below `RewriteEngine On` ?

Comment: **Make back-up copies**

Comment: The best place for such rules is not in such a dynamic configuration file _at all_. Put them into the http servers host configuration instead.

Comment: @arkascha: I have little control over the server (shared hosting)

Comment: The there are two options left: 1. change the hosting provider or 2. place those rules at the top of your set of rewriting rules.

Comment: @arkascha: I would do it very happily but I'm not the owner of the website  :-)  Ok for number 2

Answer (score 0):

What I did to serve always over https:

```
# All HTTPS to HTTP.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.yourdomainname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Where you replace yourdomainname.com with your domain.

Comment: My doubt is: should "RewriteBase /" go after?